# Device header zoom issue noticed on iPhone 6 & 6plus devices

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch

We have developed an mobile hybrid application using Sencha touch / Cordova framework integration. Once the application was launched, we noticed the system header icons/text are a little zoomed only in iPhone 6 & 6plus devices.

Does anyone have any suitable solution to overcome this system header zoom effect?

Answer (score 0):

Add "Launch Screen" to your project instead of Default image.

Follow below steps :-

1. Go to Project > General > App Icons and launch images
2. Provide Launch Screen .xib file of storyboard file in "Launch Screen File" section.